# java swing aligning radiobuttons

Tags: java, swing, radio-button, alignment, jpanel

I want to center my radibuttons in the panel, but when I center it centers according to the lenght of the text of the button, so yes they are centered but not aligned each other and look very ugly. How can I fix my code?

```
radioButtonMenuPanel = new JPanel();
    radioButtonMenuPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(radioButtonMenuPanel,
            BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    for (String item : answerItems) {
        JRadioButton radioButton = new JRadioButton(item);
        radioButton.setAlignmentX(Component.Center_ALIGNMENT);
        radioButtonMenuPanel.add(radioButton);
        group.add(radioButton);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could always use a [GridBagLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html). By using that layout, you can anchor the component in a grid in any side of the cell.

```
radioButtonMenuPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;

ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
for (String item : answerItems) {
    JRadioButton radioButton = new JRadioButton(item);
    group.add(radioButton);
    radioButtonMenuPanel.add(radioButton, gbc);
}
```

Something like that should work. By default a `GridBagLayout` centers the component in the screen in a small grid. In this case, we are just anchoring the component in the cell to the West where the component will be placed in the first column (gridx = 0), and for each radio button, it will position it next to the last component.

Hope that helped!

Answer (score 1):

How about left aligning buttons to a separate panel and then centering that panel to other panel.